# Bootstrap collapse has a jumpy transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with the transition of the bootstrap navbar.
the collapse has a jumpy transition when the collapsing element has padding

I googled this issue and it seems that the problem is the padding:

```
.menu-menu-container{
    padding: 100px 30px 60px 30px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

In fact if i remove the padding from menu-menu-container element, the animation works well, and it is very smooth

This is my codepen: http://codepen.io/mp1985/pen/EyOJYE

How can I achieve the same result without this weird issue?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The issue **is caused by the padding of the container you are collapsing**. It complicates the calculation of the height by collapse.js

Example:

HTML

```
    <div class="collapsible-div padding-values">
      // YOUR CONTENT
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.padding-values{
   padding: 20px 40px 30px;
}
```

this will be fixed if you **move the padding to an inner container**:

HTML

```
<div class="collapsible-div">
  <div class="new-container padding-values">
    // YOUR CONTENT
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The transition will also be jumpy if the inner container has some margin-top or margin-bottom values.

Answer (score 2):

Its happening because of max-height of navbar-collapse class which is 340px. Use below code to handle it.

http://codepen.io/rahulchaturvedie/pen/VjVOLa

```
.navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse, .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse {
    max-height: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a CSS transition the affected items. This will make the transition less jump as the browser will animate between the various paddings. You can target each CSS animatable property with there own timing properties. You can see all the various animatable properties here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_animatable.asp

You will want to make this selector more targeted/meaningful.

```
* {
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
```